# Angular2+: Scoped Property (<div *prop="let p=obj.prop"></div>)

Tags: html, angular, scope

I have HTML like this many times:

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countPumps"> {{"CountPumps"|localize}}</label>
            <select id="countPumps"
                    class="form-control"
                    [ngClass]="{'edited':params.countPumps.value!=null}"
                    (ngModelChange)="params.countPumps.updateRefs()"
                    (blur)="params.countPumps.checkValue()"
                    [(ngModel)]="params.countPumps.value">
                       <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
                       <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
            </select>

    </div>
```

As you can see, i need to write "param.countPumps.xxxxx" many times. This is a source of mistakes, so I would rather like something like this:

```
     <div class="form-group" *theThingIdontKnowAbout="let param=params.countPumps">
            <label for="countPumps"> {{"CountPumps"|localize}}</label>
            <select id="countPumps"
                    class="form-control"
                    [ngClass]="{'edited':param.value!=null}"
                    (ngModelChange)="param.updateRefs()"
                    (blur)="param.checkValue()"
                    [(ngModel)]="param.value">
                       <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
                       <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
            </select>

     </div>
```

So what I would want is that "*theThingIdontKnowAbout" defines the object for usage in this DIV. I have no idea what exactly to write there to make it work the way i want. ngFor does that, so I tried this, and it works, but it is suuuper hacky:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let param of [params.countPumps]">
       <label for="countPumps"> {{"CountPumps"|localize}}</label>
             <select id="countPumps"
                     class="form-control"
                     [ngClass]="{'edited':param.value!=null}"
                     (ngModelChange)="0"
                    (blur)="param.checkValue()"
                     [(ngModel)]="param.value">
             <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
             <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

If there is nothing convenient available, I will just create components instead, but at this point  this still seems like an overkill.

Comment: Why not just store a reference to `params.countPumps` in your component like: `this.countPumps= this.params.countPumps`? Then you can use it in your template as `countPumps.updateRefs()`, `countPumps.checkValue()`...

Comment: well, this still does not solve my problem. Of course, i dont have to write "param.xxx" anymore, but i will still have to explicitly write "countPumps" for every directive/emitter in the element

Comment: sorry, I'm probably missing some context and it's not completely clear to me what's your use case... Maybe using `<ng-container>` + `<ng-template>` and passing your nested object as context? `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="test; context: params"></ng-container> <ng-template #test let-param="countPumps"> // param is defined here   </ng-template>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very raw structural directive for passing a context:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myContext]' })
export class MyContextDirective implements OnChanges {
  private _viewRef: EmbeddedViewRef<any> | null = null;
  @Input('myContext') context;
  @Input('myContextPath') path: string;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this._viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {
      $implicit: this.context[this.path]
    });
  }
}
```

You can use it in your template like this:

```
<p *myContext="params; path:'countPumps'; let foo">{{foo.somePropOnCountPumps}}</p>
```